# "get_paginated_response" in django-rest-framework 3.0

Tags: python-2.7, django-rest-framework

In DRF 3.1 I can do this to get paginated response but it seems like the `get_paginated_response()` is not available in 3.0. What would be the equivalent?

```
class NoteList(ListCreateAPIView):

    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        queryset = self.get_queryset()
        paged_queryset = self.paginate_queryset(queryset)
        serializer = NoteSerializer(paged_queryset, many=True)
        return self.get_paginated_response(serializer.data)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's `PaginationSerializer`, set the serializer class by:

'DEFAULT_PAGINATION_SERIALIZER_CLASS': 'YourCustomPaginationSerializer'

or

```
class MyView(generics.GenericAPIView):
    pagination_serializer_class = YourCustomPaginationSerializerClass
```

mixin.py

```
def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    instance = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset())
    page = self.paginate_queryset(instance)
    if page is not None:
        serializer = self.get_pagination_serializer(page)
    else:
        serializer = self.get_serializer(instance, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

generics.py

```
def get_pagination_serializer(self, page):
    """
    Return a serializer instance to use with paginated data.
    """
    class SerializerClass(self.pagination_serializer_class):
        class Meta:
            object_serializer_class = self.get_serializer_class()

    pagination_serializer_class = SerializerClass
    context = self.get_serializer_context()
    return pagination_serializer_class(instance=page, context=context)
```

If you are doing the `migration` stuffs, don't forget the pagination params in settings.py or View, has been changed to new paginator.

such as. PAGINATE_BY_PARAM -> page_size_query_param.

anyhow, I think the new paginator is much confortable than the previous one.
see more detials on [Pagination Docs](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/pagination/)